# Python Moving file, if it does not exist go to the next one

Tags: python

I would like tot edit this so if the file does not exist goes to the next one. Ive tried `pass` but it does not work

Here is my script:

```
MoveTo = r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive - ISC Industries\Summer Intern 2022\Scripts\Pictures"
with open('PicsWeHave.txt') as my_file:
for filename in my_file:
    MoveFrom = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Pics")
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(MoveFrom, filename.strip()), os.path.join(MoveTo, filename.strip()))
```

Comment: why not use [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to check if the path exists or not?

Comment: FWIW if it were me I’d obfuscate any personal details from my file paths—I wouldn’t want to share a full path to my own cloud drive on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `os.path.exists` function for this.

```py
if not os.path.exists(MoveFrom):
    continue
```

Read more about it here: https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-check-if-file-exists/

Comment: Or just, 'if path exists: do things'.  No need to test for the not-exists condition.

Comment: Yes, that is also correct.

Comment: Can you explain this or show how i'd directly use it myself I cannot figure it out

Comment: This checks if the current file exists or not. If it doesn't, it will just continue to the next file.

Comment: While the answer is technically correct (it does what it says it does), it is not idiomatic Python, and it doesn't solve the actual problem: `shutil.copy()` might still fail because another process might have moved or deleted the file between the test and the copy operation - a race condition. So you still have to catch any exceptions `shutil.copy()` might raise. -- More Pythonic would be to use the "EAFP paradigm": Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission. See for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eafp-principle-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

You could check beforehand, or you could try and copy and then check if it failed with the appropriately named `FileNotFoundError`:

```
try:
    shutil.copy(..., ...)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```